# wxButton with SetDefault() no longer responds to enter on a frame

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

I have an application that was originally working with wx2.8 and has since been ported to wx3.0.  This application's frame has a "Connect" button on which SetDefault() gets called when the button is created.  Under wx2.8, this button would generate a clicked event when the enter key was recognised.  Under wx3.0, this no longer seems to function.  I have been attempting to work around this using hot keys but they present their own set of problems with modal dialogues when the enter key is defined as a hot key.  The hot key event apparently will not deliver the key event even if it was skipped.  Does anyone have any suggestions or work arounds?

Last Friday, I thought that this might have something to do with initialising the frame with the wxWANTS_CHARS style and, indeed, this is the case.  I have also found that the problem occurs if the button is not initialised with a wxID_OK ID.  The following code demonstrates the issue:

```
#include "wx/wx.h"


class MyFrame: public wxFrame
{
private:
   wxTextCtrl *text_status;
   int click_count;

public:
   MyFrame():
      wxFrame(
         0,
         wxID_ANY,
         "SetDefault",
         wxDefaultPosition,
         wxDefaultSize,
         wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wxCLIP_CHILDREN),
      click_count(0)
   {
      wxPanel *panel(new wxPanel(this));
      wxSizer *sizer(new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL));
      wxButton *button;


      text_status = new wxTextCtrl(panel, wxID_ANY);
      sizer->Add(text_status, 0, wxALL, 10);
      button = new wxButton(panel, wxID_HIGHEST + 1, "Increment");
      sizer->Add(button, 0, wxALL, 10);
      button->SetDefault();
      panel->SetSizerAndFit(sizer);
   }

   void on_increment(wxCommandEvent &event)
   {
      wxString content;
      ++click_count;
      content.Printf("%d", click_count);
      text_status->SetValue(content);
   }

   DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};


BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
EVT_BUTTON(wxID_OK, MyFrame::on_increment)
END_EVENT_TABLE()


class MyApp: public wxApp
{
   virtual bool OnInit()
   {
      MyFrame *frame(new MyFrame);
      frame->Show(true);
      SetExitOnFrameDelete(true);
      return true;
   }
};


IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around of specifying an ID of wxID_OK to the default button.

Answer (score 1):

If the default button doesn't react to Enter key presses, it looks like a bug in wxWidgets and you should [report it in the usual way](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/newticket). Please try to provide a simple example reproducing the problem, ideally as a patch to a sample, if you do this because this definitely does work in normal/most cases.

Comment: The problem appears to be a result of specifying wxWANTS_CHARS as a part of the frame style.  Since this is not (or is no longer) a documented style, I would assume that it is an invalid style.

Comment: It is valid style but it does tell that the window having it is interested in getting *all* key events, even the ones normally used for navigation, and processing them itself, so it's not completely surprising that it disables the default Enter handling.

Comment: I have found, with further experimentation that nor using wxID_OK for the default button will prevent the button from handling the enter key event.